# Vertical blue lines with long beeping when installing Windows NT 4.0

Tags: windows-nt-4

I'm trying to install Windows NT 4.0 Workstation SP1 on an unused PC (MSI J1800I, HDD 75GB 5400RPM, Samsung 2x2GB 10600MHz). Here's what I get, along with long beeping:

[image: vertical blue lines]

I have successfully installed it on virtual machine in the past, and I wonder what I'm doing wrong now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your particular problem is because NT 4.0 SP1 is apparently not compatible with anything newer than a Pentium 4. However, newer Service Packs should work (and SP6a, the last available one, is known to work).

Unfortunately, it is apparently not possible to slipstream newer packs. The only way to do it is to first install a newer Service Pack in a VM (with CPU features restricted), and then clone the disk to the physical machine.

Paraphrased from this forum thread with a very similar photo: https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=33418

---

That should at least get you past this hurdle. Note that you'll probably also need to find an AHCI driver (assuming a SATA disk) (you may be able to switch the controller into IDE mode in firmware settings), USB drivers, etc..

Comment: ... and UEFI support because it's very likely this Bay Trail doesn't even support CSM. Not even the latest service pack can give you that. Again, it has been tested and doesn't work even with a much newer XP. Your answer is just speculations.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Not only is that *clearly* not an issue (the photo the OP took is only possible *after* you've managed to boot to the point of running the installer; pure UEFI wouldn't even get to that point!), [there definitely exist J1800-based motherboards with CSM support](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=184930&pid=1650125#pid1650125) so even from a theoretical point of view, ignoring the obvious practical evidence we have here, your assertion is wrong.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia While MSI's manuals don't include detailed firmware information, I'll also point you to Asus' J1800I-C manual which clearly indicates an "Other OS" option that's listed as "non-UEFI" and *explicitly* mentions XP as supported for booting under this mode. While not the same manufacturer, again, OP's photo clearly shows boot has passed out of the firmware into the installer, which means they've gotten past that hurdle.